# Label smoothing and KL divergence

Tags: neural-networks, maximum-likelihood, regularization, kullback-leibler

I am reading the paper [Regularizing Neural Networks by Penalizing Confident Output Distributions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06548) where the authors introduce label smoothing in section 3.2. For a neural network that produces a conditional distribution $p_\theta(y|x)$ over classes $y$ given an input $x$ through a softmax function, the label smoothing loss function is defined as:

$$\mathcal L(\theta) = -\sum \log p_\theta(y|x) - D_{\mathrm{KL}}(u||p_\theta(y|x))$$

where $D_{\mathrm{KL}}$ refers to the KL divergence and $u$ the uniform distribution. However my understanding is that minimising this expression would in fact attempt to maximise the KL divergence and, since this is a measure of the dissimilarity between the posterior distribution and the uniform distribution, this would encourage the opposite of smoothing. Where is my understanding falling down here?

**Additional investigation**

Trying to get to the bottom of this I noticed a few things. In the next line of the paper the authors mention that

> By  reversing  the  direction  of  the  KL  divergence, $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(p_\theta(y|x)‖u)$,  we  recover  the  confidence penalty.

Where, for entropy function $H$ and constant $\beta$, the confidence penalty is defined as
$$\mathcal L(\theta) =−\sum \log p_\theta(y|x)−\beta H(p_\theta(y|x))$$

However when I do the derivation myself I obtain

$$\mathcal L(\theta) =−\sum \log p_\theta(y|x) + H(p_\theta(y|x))$$

Since the experiments all use positive valued $\beta$'s this suggests to me that perhaps the original equation is in fact a typo and should be *adding* the KL divergence rather than subtracting.

I have checked all the versions of the paper I could find online and the original label smoothing equation always subtracts the KL divergence.